# Transfer file via netcat as a background job in Powershell

Tags: powershell, netcat

I have 2 PCs, 1 listening for connections and the other trying to send the file.

*$dir* is a file

*"$dir.zip"* is the zipped $dir file.

I ran this command with success.

```
Get-Content "$dir.zip" | .\Netcat32.exe serveo.net PORT
```

However, I want to run it in the background, so that I can run other commands.

I followed the microsoft guides for running jobs and found AsJob and Start-Job

This command was successful, but it doesn't run in background:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "$dir.zip" | .\Netcat32.exe serveo.net PORT}
```

However, when I add the -AsJob tag at the end of the line...:

```
Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "$dir.zip" | .\Netcat32.exe serveo.net PORT} -AsJob
```

I get this error:

```
Invoke-Command : Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters.
At line:1 char:1

    + Invoke-Command -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "$dir.zip" | .\Netcat32.exe se ...
    + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
        + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Invoke-Command], ParameterBindingException
        + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeCommandCommand
```

But when I change the command to the following I get no errors, it runs in the backgorund but still no connection: (i've noticed that ComputerName is localhost by default)

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName localhost -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "$dir.zip" | .\Netcat32.exe serveo.net 55558} -AsJob
```

This command returns no errors, runs in the background, but no connection is achieved:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {Get-Content "$dir.zip" | .\WinGid.exe serveo.net PORT}
```

Tried this too, runs in bg but no TCP connection established:

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock { invoke-Command -ScriptBlock { Get-Content "$dir.zip" | .\WinGid.exe serveo.net PORT } }
```

Comment: See: about remoting.

Comment: Your job probably fails on the background. After you do "start-job .." run get-job to see id and status of that job. If you see status = failed, do receive-job jobid to see error message.

Comment: @MikeTwc It says "Completed", but I think it should be running indefinitely unless i provide -w (seconds) to netcat.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try start-process

```
start powershell -Argumentlist "Get-Content $dir.zip | .\Netcat32.exe serveo.net PORT" -noNewWindow
```

if you know how to do this in cmd below options might work
 `start ./netcat32.exe -ArgumentList "..." -nonewwindow`

or   `start-job {cmd /c "netcat32 ..."}`

Comment: I tried the second one, It looked like this: start-job {cmd /c .\Netcat32.exe serveo.net PORT < "$dir.zip"} but I got an error saying "The '<' operator is reserved for future use."